# Bash script create user

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script that creates users in Ubuntu. If the user exist, then it should asks to put in a different username that does not exist.

The same I would like for creating groups. I hope you guys can help me!

```
            if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
                read -p "Please enter a username: " username
                # Check if user exist or not
                egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
                while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do
                    read -p "User $username already exist! Please enter a different username: " username
                    exit 1
                done
                    groupadd -f "${group}"
                    useradd -m -g "${group}" "${username}"
                    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User added to system!" || echo "Could not create user!"
            else
                echo "Only root may add a user to the system."
                exit 2
            fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if ((UID!=0)); then
    echo >&2 "Only root may add a user to the system."
    exit 2
fi

read -p "Please enter a username: " username
# Check if user exist or not
if id "$username" &>/dev/null; then
    echo >&2 "User $username already exist"
    exit 1
fi
groupadd -f "$group"
if useradd -m -g "$group" "$username"; then
    echo "User added to system!"
else
    echo >&2 "Could not create user!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It's almost good! Only when a group or member exicst that it asks to put in another username or group that doesnt exist. Also I can't create a new user.

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: Well, if I try to add a user that doesn't exist does it say:
groupadd: '' is not a valid group name
useradd: group '' does not exist
Could not create user! I believe its due that it doenst ask for group name

Comment: I assuùed that group was defined earlier... You have to deal with it

Comment: I now have fixed the creation of users and groups, but how can I ask for sudo password before the prompt to enter a username.